# LinkedIn embedded post deletes itself when clicking any link

Tags: iframe, linkedin-api

When using **['Embed this post'](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/86529/embedding-content-from-the-linkedin-feed?lang=en)**, if a user clicks on a link anywhere within the iFrame it destroys the html inside. You can replicate this issue by following these steps.

1. Click '...' at the top right of a post.
2. Go to 'Embed this post' and copy the iFrame code.
3. Paste the iFrame code somewhere you can test the HTML.
4. Click a link anywhere in the embedded post.

At this point you'll see the post disappear. The head and body HTML code is destroyed.

I duplicated the issue [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YByeGK).

```
<iframe src="https://www.linkedin.com/embed/feed/update/urn:li:share:6481527492011139072" height="777" width="504" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

Try clicking on the LinkedIn icon on the top left or the like/comment/share buttons.

I tried reaching out to LinkedIn support on their website but their team directed me here.

Comment: I'm not able to replicate your issue. Did you test on the browser with disabled all plugins and did you check all errors in your browser console?

Answer (score 3):

```
Refused to display 'https://www.linkedin.com/authwall?trk=gf&trkInfo=AQFSSEZsXsstdAAAAWi4pJ9YQaz5O2_6IRmktVz1kDhxt_uchm59um--vI7OCCG1Nkz-xFDMqtML8ee4C6Min8NUMPsH3DihIAb3hbhB1WUdxyaT2NxjuAgsaAq6GPKgXJra2gA=&originalReferer=https://www.linkedin.com/embed/feed/update/urn:li:share:6481527492011139072&sessionRedirect=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.linkedin.com%2Fcompany%2Faps-technology%3Ftrk%3Dpublic-post_share-update_actor-text' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self'"
```

The content is prohibited from being displayed within an IFRAME due the Content Security Policy being set. The webserver hosting linkedin.com is configured to add a HTTP header to the response object. Specifically they are setting the Content-Security-Policy tag to frame-ancestors 'self'. There is no way you'll be able to embed their pages into a page of your own using IFRAME. There are other techniques that you could use to work around that, but none are as simple as an iframe tag.

[W3C Content Security Policy Level 3 - Frame Ancestors](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/#directive-frame-ancestors)

So, it's not something that isn't working, but it's Linkedin that don't let you do it. If you look at the urls you are going to open, also, you could see they are behind the auth wall of linkedin

Comment: Thanks @waytosay, it does seem odd that there is an option to 'Embed this Post' on  LinkedIn and they give you the IFRAME code. Do you have any information on where I could start looking for an alternative to an IFRAME?

Comment: @TimTroiano well, they want you to integrate a single Linkedin post, but not the full website. Without this, you could embed linkedin in your page in full, as you could continue to hyperlink around. I think the best approach for you is to rely on the linkedin rest API and plugins, but I don't know what you would like to do  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins?context=linkedin/consumer/context

Comment: I'm only trying to integrate a single LinkedIn post. I looked into the API and it doesn't allow you to embed your feed, you can just add a share or follow button.

Comment: Then what's the problem? As I can see, the frame is displayed correctly if it's only a post, and if somebody click a link it disappear. If you don't want it to disappear, just put a div as an overlay with 0 opacity on the frame that, when clicked, opens the post link in target blank, letting the user to login in the linkedin auth_wall and to interact with the post

Comment: That's my current solution but it seems like a serious bug on LinkedIn's end. I tried emailing their support and they told me to post my question here. When you embed a post or a feed from Facebook or Instagram there are no security errors that break the content. Until LinkedIn solves the bug on their end I guess this is the only viable solution.

Comment: @TimTroiano Well Tim, if I need to guess, it's not a bug but it's a behavior of the browser when handling with such errors. I guess when chrome receives a Content Security Policy about a frame, it disables it in full, as it take it as unsafe or not permitted by the server. I don't think Linkedin can do anything about it :) but if you find more, please update this post

Comment: If you see how Facebook's embed option works it doesn't break the plugin when you click a link. If you're authenticated it takes the action and if you're not it opens a window to have the user log in. None of the links break the iFrame. If this is the intended effect from LinkedIn I don't think it makes for a great user experience! Thank you for your help @waytosay https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-posts/